# mingw 4.6.1 atomic fail?

Tags: mingw, c++11, atomic, boost-thread

So I discovered that gcc already had a working implementation of `std::atomic` so I wanted to try it out, here is my example using boost thread 1.48 and `std::atomic`:

```
#include <iostream>
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

class Server
{
    public:
    atomic<bool> running;
    thread main_server_thread;


    void func1()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    void func2()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    void func3()
    {
        while(running)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
    void func4()
    {
        string input;
        while(running)
        {
            //do stuff
            input.clear();
            getline(cin,input);
            if(input=="quit")running=false;
        }
    }

    void main_function()
    {
        thread thrd1(bind(&Server::func1,this));
        thread thrd2(bind(&Server::func2,this));
        thread thrd3(bind(&Server::func3,this));
        thread thrd4(bind(&Server::func4,this));

        while(running)
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        thrd1.join();
        thrd2.join();
        thrd3.join();
        thrd4.join();
    }

    Server()
    {
        running=true;
        main_server_thread = thread(&Server::main_function,this);
    }
};



int main()
{
    Server* serv = new Server();
    serv->main_server_thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Now while `running` remains `true` all is fine but when the user inputs `quit` and `running` is set to `false` some threads end and some don't. This happens with and without optimizations. Is this working as intended? In my understanding of atomics the reads shouldn't conflict with the one write so the threads should see the `running=false` at some point.

EDIT:
Disassembly of func1:

```
void func1()
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
        {
            while(running)
   6:   90                      nop
   7:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
   a:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
   d:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   12 <__ZN6Server5func1Ev+0x12>
  12:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  14:   75 f1                   jne    7 <__ZN6Server5func1Ev+0x7>
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
  16:   c9                      leave  
  17:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Works fine on regular GCC. Can you disassemble `func1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the disassembly shows, this program, when compiled with mingw, does not treat `running` as an atomic: it is loaded with a regular `mov 0x8(%ebp),%eax` without synchronization.

Compare to the output of gcc-4.6.2 on linux/x86_64:

```
_ZN6Server5func1Ev:      // Server::func1()
    jmp     .L78
.L79:
    // do stuff
.L78:
    mfence
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax // load from `running`
    mfence
    testb   %al, %al
    jne     .L79
    ret
```

Either mingw doesn't support that yet, or something is missing in its configuration.

Comment: I wonder if there is a quick fix for this. I can't find anything related to this except this:[link](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=102435&aid=3420359&group_id=2435)